# Trigger data response from .aspx page

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint
import requests

url = 'http://estadistico.ut.com.sv/OperacionDiaria.aspx'

s = requests.Session()

pagereq = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pagereq.content, 'lxml')

viewstategenerator = soup.find("input", attrs = {'id': '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'})['value']
viewstate = soup.find("input", attrs = {'id': '__VIEWSTATE'})['value']
eventvalidation = soup.find("input", attrs = {'id': '__EVENTVALIDATION'})['value']

eventtarget = 'ASPxDashboardViewer1'
DXCss = '1_33,1_4,1_9,1_5,15_2,15_4'
DXScript = '1_232,1_134,1_225,1_169,1_187,15_1,1_183,1_182,1_140,1_147,1_148,1_142,1_141,1_143,1_144,1_145,1_146,15_0,15_6,15_7'
eventargument = {"Task":"Export","ExportInfo":{"Mode":"SingleItem","GroupName":"pivotDashboardItem1","FileName":"Generación+por+tipo+de+tecnología+(MWh)","ClientState":{"clientSize":{"width":509,"height":385},"titleHeight":48,"itemsState":[{"name":"pivotDashboardItem1","headerHeight":34,"position":{"left":11,"top":146},"width":227,"height":108,"virtualSize":'null',"scroll":{"horizontal":'true',"vertical":'true'}}]},"Format":"Excel","DocumentOptions":{"paperKind":"Letter","pageLayout":"Portrait","scaleMode":"AutoFitWithinOnePage","scaleFactor":1,"autoFitPageCount":1,"showTitle":'true',"title":"Operación+Diaria","imageFormatOptions":{"format":"Png","resolution":96},"excelFormatOptions":{"format":"Csv","csvValueSeparator":","},"commonOptions":{"filterStatePresentation":"None","includeCaption":'true',"caption":"Generación+por+tipo+de+tecnología+(MWh)"},"pivotOptions":{"printHeadersOnEveryPage":'true'},"gridOptions":{"fitToPageWidth":'true',"printHeadersOnEveryPage":'true'},"chartOptions":{"automaticPageLayout":'true',"sizeMode":"Zoom"},"pieOptions":{"autoArrangeContent":'true'},"gaugeOptions":{"autoArrangeContent":'true'},"cardOptions":{"autoArrangeContent":'true'},"mapOptions":{"automaticPageLayout":'true',"sizeMode":"Zoom"},"rangeFilterOptions":{"automaticPageLayout":'true',"sizeMode":"Stretch"},"imageOptions":{},"fileName":"Generación+por+tipo+de+tecnología+(MWh)"},"ItemType":"PIVOT"},"Context":"BwAHAAIkY2NkNWRiYzItYzIwNS00MDIyLTkzZjUtYWQ0NzVhYTM5Y2E3Ag9PcGVyYWNpb25EaWFyaWECAAIAAAAAAMByQA==","RequestMarker":1,"ClientState":{}}

postdata = {'__EVENTTARGET': eventtarget,
            '__EVENTARGUMENT': eventargument,
            '__VIEWSTATE': viewstate,
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': viewstategenerator,
            '__EVENTVALIDATION': eventvalidation,
            'DXScript': DXScript,
            'DXCss': DXCss
           }

datareq = s.post(url, data = postdata)

print datareq.text
```

I'm trying to scrape data from [this](http://estadistico.ut.com.sv/OperacionDiaria.aspx) .aspx webpage.  The page loads the data dynamically via javascript so scraping directly with requests/BeautifulSoup won't work.

By looking at the network traffic I can see that when you click the export (Exportar a) button for an element, select a type of export (excel, csv) then confirm a POST request is made to the page.  It returns a base64 encoded string of the data I need.  As far as I can tell there is no way to make a GET request for the file directly as it is only generated when requested.

What I'm trying to do is is copy the POST request which triggers the csv response.  So first I scrape for __VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR and __EVENTVALIDATION.  __EVENTTARGET, DXCSS and DXScript look to be fixed.  __EVENTARGUMENT is copied directly from the POST request.

My code returns a server application error.  I'm thinking the problem is either a) wrong __EVENTARGUMENT (maybe part dynamic rather than fixed?), b) not really understanding how .aspx pages work or c) what I'm trying to do isn't possible with these tools.

I did look at using selenium to trigger the data export but I couldn't see a way to capture the server response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get help from someone who knows more about aspx pages than me.

Link to the Github gist that provides the solution.

https://gist.github.com/jarek/d73c672d8dd4ddb48d80bffc4d8038ba