# How do I get '__VIEWSTATE' and '__EVENTVALIDATION' on an asp.net page using python

Tags: python, asp.net, beautifulsoup, python-requests

On the page, there is a drop-down menu and a button which displays a table on the page when clicked. I need to scrape data from this table.  The '__VIEWSTATE' and '__EVENTVALIDATION' values are different from the page before the button is clicked and after. My problem is I can only get my hands on the values from the page before button is clicked using something like this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with requests.Session() as html:
    s = html.get(url, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.content,"lxml")
    data.append(tuple(('__VIEWSTATE',inputvs)))
    data.append(tuple(('__EVENTVALIDATION',inputev)))
```

I need the correct values in order to post the valid data. However, above script will only get me only the the values from before the button is clicked. Please HELP!!!!!!!!

Comment: code from button clicks is usually executed through javascript, which BeautifulSoup has no control over, you'd have better luck looking into PhantomJS or Selenium.

Comment: That said though, it sounds similar to this question: [Trigger data response from .aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722069/trigger-data-response-from-aspx-page)

Comment: It might be possible to do this using `requests` and a study of the network tab. Can you post the URL?

Comment: @Mahesh unfortunately, It's an corp internal site. Thanks anyway

Comment: @downshift I'm assuming the button is executed through javascript. I found this from html.The variable below is the button's HTML ID
 //<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._updateControls('ctl00$MainContent$cmdGoXml', 90);
//]]>

Comment: I would not like use selenium because of time consumption. Is there way to get through without using it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you find the answer? If not this may help.

I did fetch the page first then extract the solid `__viewstate` and `__eventvaldation` fresh values from the first response, put them in a post request with form data and sent it.
Waited for a second response and extract it in the script. 
This the only way to ensure that the these hashes have the correct values that the server is expecting.